# devise+cancan don't recognize ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I have a problem, when i acces to manage users with cancan, said "You are not authorized to access this page." 
here is my code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)


    if user.tipo == 'c'

        can :manage, :User

    end 
  end 
end
```

and here is my controller User

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @users = User.excludes(:id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created User." 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted User."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end 
end
```

and here my routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :proyects
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
  resources :users, :controller => "user"
```

Some body know how to solve it?? or someone has just happened

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to tell us what steps you did leading up to the error and take some basic debugging steps yourself. Like checking what `current_user` returns.

Answer (score 1):

The class name in ability definition is wrong.

Change `ability.rb` as given below :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.tipo == 'c'
      can :manage, User
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, god bless you!